# React this.setState not updating my value, on firebase changes are showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with my code. I am trying to make a notes in react + fireabse. Adding notes to fireabse works and setState shows them, but if I want to change the value of the note, second setState does not change it but in firebase the note will change its value.

Here is my code

```
constructor() {
 super(); 
 this.app = firebase.initializeApp(DB_CONFIG);
 this.database = this.app.database().ref().child('notes');

 this.state = {
  notes: [],
 };
}

componentDidMount() {
 this.database.on('child_added', snap => {
   this.state.notes.push(new Note(snap.key, snap.val().noteContent));
   this.setState({
     notes: this.state.notes
   });
 });

 this.database.on('child_changed', snap => {
   this.state.notes.forEach(note => {
     if(snap.key === note.id) {
       note.id = snap.key;
       note.noteContent = snap.val().noteContent;
     }
   });
  this.setState({
     notes: this.state.notes,
   });
 });
}

addNote(note) {
 this.database.push().set({
   noteContent: note,
 });
}

changeNote(id, note) {
 this.database.child(id).update({
   noteContent: note,
 });
}

render() {
return (
  <div>

    <div> {
      this.state.notes.map(note => {
          return (
            <NoteComponent noteContent={note.noteContent} 
              noteId={note.id} 
              key={note.id}
              changeNote={this.changeNote.bind(this)}>
            </NoteComponent>
          )
        })
      }
  </div>

  <div>

  </div>
    <NoteFormComponent 
      addNote={this.addNote.bind(this)}>
    </NoteFormComponent>
  </div>
);
```

}

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem lines:

```
this.state.notes.push(new Note(snap.key, snap.val().noteContent));
```

or

```
 this.state.notes.forEach(note => {
     if(snap.key === note.id) {
       note.id = snap.key;
       note.noteContent = snap.val().noteContent;
     }
   });
  this.setState({
     notes: this.state.notes,
   });
```

You cannot change the value of the state like this. You HAVE to use `setState`.
To fix this you need to:

1. copy(deepclone) the state array (You shoudl use ImmutableJS but this will work for testing: `const copiedArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array)))`
2. Do the changes to the copied array `copiedArray`.
3. `setState('notes', copiedArray)`

Other suggestions:

I would suggest to you to do the following. Isolate the firebase layer from the viewing layer. Mixing responsibilities of the component with the db communication is not recommanded.
After you do that. you will pass the list of  note from outside the component. And any method working on the  database(firebase in you case will come as a param also.)

```
// Notes Container
    const notes = FireBaseConnector.getNotes();
    const {
        add,
        edit,
        delete,
    } = FireBaseConnector

    <Notes notes={notes}
         onAdd={add}
         onEdit={edit}
         onRemove={delete}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
const newNotes = [...this.state.notes]
const newNode = {
  id: snap.key,
  noteContent: snap.val().noteContent,
}
newNotes.push(newNode)
this.setState({
     notes: newNotes,
});
```

you cannot just push you need to replace the node array with the new array. immutability need to be followed to tell react to rerender

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but in your code, I add a new element, and I want only to change noteContent selected node, as it happens in firebase but this.setState doesnt change noteContent, after refreshing the page, the data will be downloaded from firebase and will look the way it wants